# Add arrays that are the length of the values from another array?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a tablelayout for a game. Each table has amount of players.

These amounts are in tables[].

tables[0] = 9, tables[1] = 9, tables[2] = 8 etc.

The length of tables[] is the amount of tables there are.

the value of tables[0] (so 9) is the amount of players table1[] should have.

So i got 2 arrays:

```
tables[]
table1[]
```

Tables[0] (first value) is 9, i want the size of table1[] to be 9, is this possible?

I tried a while loop, but i can only call the table1[] when its in the loop, not outside.

Is it possible to fill multiple ints from an array? like

```
int table1 = tables[0]
int table2 = tables[1]
```

i cant call table1 and table2 in a for loop with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
 tablei = tables[i]
}
```

Comment: `tables[1]` is not the first value it is the second. The count starts in 0. To create an array with 9 elements on it  do: `tables[] = new int[9]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried a while loop, but i can only call the table1[] when its in the loop, not outside.

You probably defined it in the loop.

Assuming the arrays contains integers, the answer to your question would be

```
int[] table1 = new int[tables[0]];
```

**EDIT:** I get your edited problem. You can't put a variable into a name and expect Java to understand that, so `tablei` doesn't work. You may want to use a 2-dimensional array here, that is, an array of an array.

For your understanding, I changed what you called `tables` to `tableSizes` as it describes the variable's purpose better and I can use `tables` as the 2-dimensional array then.

```
int[] tableSizes = new int[9];
tableSizes[0] = 9;
tableSizes[1] = 9;
tableSizes[2] = 8;
// and so on
int[][] tables = new int[9][]; // create the 'outer' array
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    tables[i] = new int[tableSizes[i]]; // create the 'inner' arrays
}
// access like this
int var = tables[0][1]; // second value of first table
tables[1][0] = 1; // first value of second table
```

As mentioned, we start counting with 0, so in my example your `table1` became `tables[0]`.

Comment: don't know if you get notified about edits, so: done :-)

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
double[] table1 = new double[table[0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] playersPerTable = new int[tables.length][];
for (int tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < tables.length; ++tableIndex) {
    playersPerTable[tableIndex] = new int[tables[tableIndex]];
}
...
playersPerTable[tableIndex][playerIndex] = 13;
```

Classes like `List`, `ArrayList`, `Map` and `Set` might be more dynamic.
As `tables[i] == playersPerTable[i].length` you might not need `tables`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;


public class tables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] tables = {9, 4, 5};
        int[] tables1 = new int[tables[0]];
        System.out.println(tables1.length);
    }
}
```

Output:
`9`